# Handle dot at the end of URL in routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got an Asp.Net MVC 5 website. In `Web.config` file, I have these in the `handlers` section:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler,                 System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0,                 Culture=neutral,                 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" path="/user/*" verb="GET" />
</handlers>
```

Basically I want everything after the `website.com/user/...` to be captured by the `UserController`. But unfortunately it doesn't work if it ends with a dot `.` For instance:
`website.com/user/test.`

How can I change it to fix this issue?